# Why does an EPS picture exported from R look so different in Word2010?

Tags: r

This is the original picture in R:

[image: the original picture in R]

However when I use Postscript to export it, then the font in the PES is very very bold and different from the original one. Could you tell me how I can resolve this?

The output in Word2010:

[image: the output ESP in Word2010]

the R code as below:

```
setEPS()
postscript("whatever4.eps", family="Elephant", colormodel="cmyk")
orthogram(resid, tre)# this orthogram is a function of R package"adephylo"
dev.off()
```

Comment: why are you setting `family="Elephant"` ... ?

Comment: The EPS interpreter in Word isn't very good, particularly the WYSIWYG preview. It may print OK. See here: http://superuser.com/q/426405/58541

Comment: Word and Postscript/PDF still don't play well together. I usually produce a PNG of sufficient resolution for inclusion in Word documents.

Comment: eps format includes a low-res 'thumbnail' embedded. Word does not know how to handle eps, so what you see is only the thumbnail.

Comment: If this is for a journal submission (many require .eps format), then typically you can submit the images as separate files rather than embedded into the document. Check with journal requirements, but this is usually the least painful way to go.

Comment: @Ben Bolker, Hi, thank you very much, the font setting is ad hoc, no special reason, I had tried the "Arial" font, but get the same unwanted result

Comment: @James, thank you for your answer,  it give me the right direction. Thanks again.

Comment: @Roland,dww, thank both of you, now I make sense of it with your help, dww, thank you for your suggestion about the journal submission.I am a ecologist,  plotting for my research paper of "tree bark phylogenetic signal analysis".